# CSS solo me toma algunas cosas

Tags: html, css, html5, vscode, sass

No recibe todas las etiquetas que le escrbio usando CSS o SASS, no le quita la decoración a la lista ni lo remarcable cada que se selecciona. Tampoco se separan ya teniendo el display flex ni grid

```css
.Navbar {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="Navbar">
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Ya no se que más hacer jaja, ser nuevo juega en contra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aplicar los estilos a los elementos debes seleccionarlos correctamente. En tu caso le estas aplicando los estilos al contenedor **'section'** con la clase **'Navbar'**. Es decir, el contenedor **'section'** es solamente una estructura semántica el cual no contiene contenido dentro de él.

Lo que estás tratando de realizar es aplicar los estilos a los contenidos que están dentro de la estructura de **'section'** o **'Navbar'**. Es decir, hay que seleccionar los elementos correctos, que en el ejemplo dado serían los elementos: **'ul'** y **'a'**.

El elemento **ul** por defecto pone el estilo para cada elemento 'li' que se genera y el elemento **a** genera los estilos para identificar que es un vínculo.

Pasando a la parte práctica te recomendaría modificar la estructura HTML de esta manera:

```
<body>

  <header>
    <nav class='navbar'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>
```

Esta estructura HTML sería semánticamente correcta ya que las barras de navegación generalmente se colocan dentro de la estructura de **header** y además es más limpia porque no estás usando contenedores de forma innecesaria. También, hemos cambiado el nombre de la clase reemplazando **Navbar** por **navbar**. Para las clases o ID te recomiendo no utilizar mayúsculas al inicio de la palabra.

Ahora, para la práctica de los estilos en CSS debes realizar las siguientes modificaciones.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, esto me sirvió mucho!

Comment: Me alegra mucho! Espero que puedas aplicar ese conocimiento a tus futuros proyectos!

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir lo que quieres debes aplicar los estilos directamente a las etiquetas, así por ejemplo si quieres quitar los puntos de la lista, debes aplicar el estilo a los elementos "li".

```css
.Navbar li {
  list-style: none;
}

.Navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```